# How to get a git diffs file list without the deleted ones?

Tags: git

Currently I use this command to get a list of changed files between the `develop` and `master` branches:

```
git diff remotes/origin/master origin/develop --name-only > diffs.txt
```

Is there a way to exclude files that I deleted on the `develop`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: `--diff-filter=d`.

Longer, but still not very long:  See the `--diff-filter` option.  In particular, `diff-filter=AM`, for instance, keeps only those entries whose status is either A or M.  These letter codes are the same as the ones shown by `git diff --name-status` (and for that matter, by `git status --short`)—so to show *only* deleted files, you'd want `--diff-filter=D`.

Uppercase letters are inclusive, so if you want everything *except* D, you could use `--diff-filter=ABCMRTUX`, which is every possible code except D, but there's a shorter variant: lowercase means *exclude*, so `--diff-filter=d` means *everything except status code D*, which is of course what you want.

Note that several codes should never occur for many cases, e.g., U (unmerged) can only occur during a conflicted merge and X (unknown) should never occur at all (it's a placeholder for Git to announce a self-detected bug).  Codes B and C can only occur if you turn on the corresponding options.  Code R occurs only if you turn on rename detection, but it is now on by default in Git 2.9 and later.  Code T is rare: it means a regular file was replaced by a symlink, or vice versa, or that what was a submodule is now a regular file or symlink, or vice versa.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203